# How can I combine rows based on a specific parameter in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   ID Smoker Asthma  Age Sex COPD Event_Date
1   1      0      0  65   M    0   12-2009
2   1      0      1  65   M    0   21-2009
3   1      0      1  65   M    0   23-2009
4   2      1      0  67   M    0   19-2010
5   2      1      0  67   M    0   21-2010
6   2      1      1  67   M    1   01-2011
7   2      1      1  67   M    1   02-2011
8   3      2      1  77   F    0   09-2015
9   3      2      1  77   F    1   10-2015
10  3      2      1  77   F    1   10-2015
```

I would like to know whether it would be possible it combine my rows in order to achieve a dataset like this:

```
  ID Smoker   Asthma  Age Sex  COPD  Event_Data
    1   0      1      65   M   0      12-2009
    2   1      1      66   M   1      19-2010
    3   2      1      77   F   1      09-2015
```

I have tried using the unique function, however this doesn't give me my desired output and repeats the ID for multiple rows.

This is an example of the code i've tried

```
Data2<-unique(Data)
```

I do not just want the first row because I want to include each column status. For example, just getting the first row would not include the COPD status which occurs in the later rows for each ID.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. You for sure don't want unique entries, because every entry is unique in your dataset. Do you want the first entry of each ID?

Comment: why is smoker always 0 in your desired dataset? why is Asthma 0,1,2?  Where does Dead come from?

Comment: @Julian_Hn I do not just want the first row because I'd like to include the column status that appear in rows further down for each ID in a single row.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I have edited my post so it makes more sense. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative Solution:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(ID, Age, Sex, Smoker) %>%
  summarise(Asthma = !is.na(match(1, Asthma)),
            COPD = !is.na(match(1, COPD)),
            Event_Date = first(Event_Date)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric)


# A tibble: 3 x 7
     ID   Age Sex   Smoker Asthma  COPD Event_Date
  <int> <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     
1     1    65 M          0      1     0 12-2009   
2     2    67 M          1      1     1 19-2010   
3     3    77 F          2      1     1 09-2015
```

Comment: When I try this with a larger dataframe with additional columns similar to the ones above, I return the error "column can't be modified because its a grouping variable". is there a way i can overcome this?

Comment: The `group_by` is a workaround. I put in there all the columns that have identical values for every ID so I don't have to change them in `summarise()` but they nevertheless appear in the result. If you change a column inside `summarise()` it musn't be in the `group_by()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the (first)  row for each `ID` you can try something like this:

```
d <- structure(list(ID         = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                    Smoker     = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                    Asthma     = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                    Age        = c(65L, 65L, 65L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 77L, 77L, 77L), 
                    Sex        = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                       .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
                    COPD       = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
                    Event_Date = structure(c(5L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
                                           .Label = c("01-2011", "02-2011", "09-2015", 
                                                      "10-2015", "12-2009", "19-2010", 
                                                      "21-2009", "21-2010", "23-2009"), 
                                           class = "factor")), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))


d[!duplicated(d$ID), ]

#   ID Smoker Asthma Age Sex COPD Event_Date
# 1  1      0      0  65   M    0    12-2009
# 4  2      1      0  67   M    0    19-2010
# 8  3      2      1  77   F    0    09-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max` when you need a value further down and `dplyr::first` for others, here an example

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Smoker=first(Smoker), Asthma=max(Asthma, na.rm = TRUE))
```